# Compare byte[] to T

Tags: c#, generics

I want to make a list of pointers to locations that contains a certain value in the process memory of another process.  The value can be a short, int, long, string, bool or something else.

My idea is to use Generics for this. I have one problem with making it, how can I tell the compiler to what type he needs to convert the byte array?

This is what I made:

```
    public List<IntPtr> ScanProccessFor<T>(T ItemToScanFor)
    {
        List<IntPtr> Output = new List<IntPtr>();

        IntPtr StartOffset = SelectedProcess.MainModule.BaseAddress;
        int ScanSize = SelectedProcess.MainModule.ModuleMemorySize;

        for (int i = 0; i < ScanSize; i++)
            if (ReadMemory(SelectedProcess, StartOffset + i, (UInt16)Marshal.SizeOf(ItemToScanFor)) == ItemToScanFor)
                Output.Insert(Output.Count,StartOffset + i);

        return Output;
    }
```

How can I tell the compiler that he needs to convert the byte[] to type T?

Comment: Your compiler is a "he"? :)

Comment: @Ed odd; when I ask mine, it says "My name is legion, for we are many"

Comment: At least 3 guys (myself included) edited the post and we didn't change it =)

Comment: @MarcGravell: Well I sincerely hope that my compiler is not infected with demons. :D

Comment: What does it *mean* for you to convert a byte[] to a T? What should happen if T is for example of type Button or FileStream?

Comment: I believe he is attempting to deserialize/copy an object that exists in memory which belongs to another process.  ReadMemory is returning `byte[]`, and OP wants that `byte[]` to be translated to the actual object (of type T) the data represents.

Comment: You are comparing a reference to a managed object to a pointer in another process ? I am thinking that is not going to produce the results you are looking for. However, if T is a struct and you are comparing the contents of the struct to a chunk of memory in another process, that might have a chance of working, assumign the contents are the same. However, I think you will need to martial the manged object into memory first and then compare byte to byte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a little bit confusing, but I'll try to answer what I can

Instead of taking a generic type, I would probably write a method that takes an instance of an interface like `IConvertableToByteArray` or something.

```
public IConvertableToByteArray
{    
    public byte[] ToByteArray();
}
```

Then If you needed to allow a specific type to be compatible with that method, you could make an encapsulating class

```
public IntConvertableToByteArray : IConvertableToByteArray
{
    public int Value{get; set;}

    public byte[] ToByteArray()
    {
        insert logic here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Marshal.StructureToPtr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.structuretoptr.aspx) to get an unmanaged representation of the structure (which has to be a 'simple' structure).  You might need to special case strings though.

You should also think about the alignment constraints on what you are searching for -- advancing through memory 1 byte at a time will be very slow and wasteful if the item must be 4 or 8 byte aligned.